# xpath: concatenate sibling node text

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the sample XML data:

```
<root>
  <a>
    <id>1</id>
    <status>on</status>
    <level>4</level>
    <otherData>asdfasdfsdfvasdF</otherData>
    <b>
        <name>A1</name>
    </b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <id>2</id>
    <status>on</status>
    <level>8</level>
    <otherData>asdfasdfsdfvasdF</otherData>
    <b>
        <name>TEST</name>
    </b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <id>3</id>
    <status>off</status>
    <level>2</level>
    <otherData>asdfasdfsdfvasdF</otherData>
    <b>
        <name>A1</name>
    </b>
  </a>
</root>
```

I'd like to write an XPath expression that will evaluate to:

```
1 on
3 off
```

That is, I'd like to extract the text of the `id` node and concatenate it with the `status` node. There is an additional condition: I only want to do this for cases where the `name` is "A1". The XPath expression to just get the `id` is this:

```
//name[text()="A1"]/../../id/text()
```

And here's an attempt to concatenate `id` with it's sibling `status`, which does not work.

```
//name[text()="A1"]/../../concat(id/text() , status/text())
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? And if so, what would be the correct XPath expression?

---

To clarify: I'm not doing any transformations with this expression, I'm just plugging it into an XPath expression evaluator (such as in Notepad++ or JEdit - via plugins) to help debug subtle data errors in very large XML files. In this example, certain combinations of `id` and `status` might not be correct if the `b` child element has `name="A1"`, so I am trying to find them all with one simple expression rather than scrolling through the file by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath 2.0:

```
for $n in /root/a[b/name[.='A1']] return concat($n/id, ' ' , $n/status)
```

Result:

```
1 on
3 off
```

Tested in [Oxygen XML Editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com), a very good tool IMHO.

Comment: Hmmmm... the plugin that I'm using for Notepad++ does not seem to support XPath 2.0, nor does the JEdit plugin (they both give me "illegal token"-type errors). Any good tools/editors you can recommend that would be able to evaluate this? Or a way to do this in Xpath 1.x, if it's possible.

Comment: Oxygen looks like a pretty slick tool, but I don't need most of the features in it, and I don't think I can get budget for those licenses. This is really just something I need on my workstation to debug and correct XML files until a fix goes in to production in a couple of weeks.

Comment: XQuery is based on XPath 2.0 and there is a [jEdit XQuery plugin](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?XQuery). I haven't tested this plugin and it uses an old version of Saxon (Saxon 7), but perhaps it can be useful anyway.

Comment: Aha I got it working, but I had to install the SaxonPlugin to support XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You just need to add desired formatting )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//name[text()='A1']"></xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="name[text()='A1']">
      <xsl:value-of select="../../id"/>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="../../status"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear: I'm not doing this in a stylesheet, I'm using this to debug large XML files that have subtle data errors.