# XPath: Concatenate text within node and its directly following sibling

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

I am beginner in XSLT and XPath, learning mostly by example and working on a project.

I am trying to concatenate `text()` content of two nodes. With each apperance of node `a`, the `text()` content of node `a` should be concatenated with `text()` content of next following sibling node `b`. This concatenated content should be registered as `text()` new node `foo` in the same place, as node `a` was.

Example input:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a>First text</a>
    <b>Text</b>
    <c>Indiferent tag.</c>
    <a>Another "a" test.</a>
    <b>ěščřžýáíéúů</b>
    <c>Another indiferent tag.</c>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expected (hoped for) output:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <foo>First text Text</foo>
    <c>Indiferent tag.</c>
    <foo>Another "a" test. ěščřžýáíéúů</foo>
    <c>Another indiferent tag.</c>
  </body>
</html>
```

Stylesheet I am currently using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="html/body/a">
    <foo>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(text(), folowing-sibling::b[1]/text())"/>
    </foo>
  </xsl:template>
```

Just errors out because of wrong XPath statement.

How can I improve the stylesheet to get desired result?

**Note:** I am aware of existence of following issues and its answers: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742801/xpath-concatenate-sibling-node-text), [This brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246371/how-to-get-the-following-sibling-in-xslt) and others, but I am having trouble applying them to my specific case.

Furthermore, for this project I am stuck with `python lxml`; which I believe is I can use only XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0. Those are limits that I would like for anybody kind enough to help me to follow. However, I am learning with `saxon`, so solutions using advanced versions would be also nice from learning perspective.

Lastly, this is just a example snippet from larger HTML file, which I am trying to convert to valid (and for my use case handy) XML, and there is a lot of grouping involved (I would need to group by key `foo` as well eventually), so the solution should preferably use identity transform overloading, which will hopefully enable me to use it beyond this example ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you could do this.

Not sure about your grouping comment at the end of your question though...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="a">
    <foo>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., following-sibling::b[1])"/>
    </foo>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Remove b nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="b"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjin9